# Fixing bug in geom_smooth method in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a smooth curve plot for the data I have. I have data in a text file, say file.txt which is a tab seperated file and headers are `A` and `B` like

```
A    B
0.1  0.2
  .....
  .....
```

There are about 30000 such data points under both `A` and `B`

I am using the following code for that:

```
dstr_data <- read.table("file.txt", header=T, sep="\t")

ggplot(dstr_data,aes(xaxis))+geom_smooth(method="auto",aes(y=dstr_data$A)
,colour="red",size=0.75)+geom_smooth(method="auto",aes(y=dstr_data$B),
colour="darkgreen",alpha=0.5,size=0.75)+opts(title=expression("Test Plot"),
panel.background = theme_rect(fill='blanchedalmond', colour='black'))+
xlab("Data")+ylab("Values")

geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is >=1000, 
so using gam with formula: y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.
```

`xaxis` in my code holds numbers from 1 to 30000. So my X-axis would be numbers from 1 to 30000. Y-axis would be values from the file.txt. So, I am trying to plot two curves on one graph now.

I want to know why this Error is displayed and how I can fix it. I want to use a method that gives me a smooth curve of the data and not a straight line and hence I do not want to use the lm,glm methods.

Also I get the graph only for a subset of data and not the entire data. Why does this happen?

Can someone help me in this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: When I use your code I get the same text, but its not an error.  Its just telling you which smoothing method it choose since you asked it to pick (you specified `method='auto'`).  If you don't want to see those messages, specify the method you want (see `?stat_smooth` for more info)

Comment: Thank you! I thought that was an error and it was truncating my data. Also, I want to understand how exactly this smoothing function works. I just found in the stat_smooth tutorial that it helps the eye in reading the differences in data. But, I want to know the logic behind it so that I can understand what's going on. Thank you once again.

Comment: That is a noble goal, but be forewarned a lot of the ggplot2 code is written in an OO style and is hard to wade through.  You can look at what's going on inside `stat_smooth` [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/7cbd6c29d096d31a1e48b805260cee673188a299/R/stat-smooth.r)